# How can I see the crash reports of IOS App which is not yet there in the Apple Store?

Tags: testing, swift2, ios9, testflight, xcode7.3

I am new to iOS platform(SWIFT - iOS9- Xcode7.3), I developed one Social Networking app in Swift and want to see crash reports of the app in the mobile as well as in Xcode. I did the process of Certifications,App ID, Provisioning Certificates and all...(whether all these are necessary for testing the app) I started with test-flight but I am not finding their SDK. So how to go with the step by step process of testing the iOS app before I go with the production.

Let me know if there are any other tools other than test flight. or What is the right way to do the process of testing and then production to the Apple Store. I dint find any proper answers please help.

Answer (score 1):

Test flight is integrated with apple iTuneConnect app store build,As of now you can not get the crash report for beta build. App store build will not share the crash report to developer until it was not shared by user device (by enabling Share with app developer setting).There are many [crash reporting tools](https://www.raywenderlich.com/33669/overview-of-ios-crash-reporting-tools-part-1)
I will recommend to use [fabric](https://docs.fabric.io/ios/fabric/getting-started.html)